# Partial derivative isn't continuous

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I would like verification on a calculation that shows $f$ below is differentiable at $(0,0)$ but $f_x$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

$$f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})$$

when $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.

So assuming for the moment that the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ (it is), this shows that $f_x(0,0)$ exists.  In fact, it is easy to see $f_x(0,0)=0$ by applying the definition of the derivative and using the squeeze theorem.  Then by standard computation we get that away from the origin 
$$f_x(x,y)=2x\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)-\frac{\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

Here is where I'm a little fuzzy....   I found that $\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)} f_x=0$ and so this isn't helpful.   I need to find a path that makes the limit not equal to zero, right?  What if I find a path where the limit doesn't exist? Is this enough?  I have a result that says

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}g(x,y)=\lim_{r\to 0^+} g(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$$

I guess I prefer working in these coordinates because then I don't have to worry about the path.  I computed the following

$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} f_x(r,\theta)=2r\cos\theta\left(\sin(r^{-2})-r^{-2}\cos(r^{-2})\right)$$

Where $2r\cos\theta\sin(\frac{1}{r^2})\to0$ by the squeeze theorem and the second term's limit does not exist (right?)  So I have two questions:

1) Does this prove that $f_x$ is not continuous since this limit does not exist? Or should I work in Cartesian coordinates and find a path that shows the limit depends on the path.

2) Can I always do this switch to polar coordinates (where the above centred equation holds true)?  Does there need to be polar symmetry?  I don't believe this function has polar symmetry.

Comment: Actually...... it now seems that $\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)} f_x$ DNE but that is beside the point.  I don't really see a need to edit the question.

Comment: The continuity of first partial derivatives isn't required for a function to be differentiable: it is enough *all but one of them is continuous* to get differentiability, though. Anyway, if you choose a way in some kind of coordinates *where the function's defined* and you get the limit you want doesn't exist this is enough to deduce **the** limit doesn't exist and thus the function isn't continuous there and yes: you can always switch to polar coord., observing the above.

Comment: Thank you.  I can easily see that the function is differentiable btw because $\Delta z=f(\Delta x,\Delta y)-f(0,0)=f_x(0,0)\Delta x +f_y(0,0)\Delta y+\varepsilon_1 \Delta x+\varepsilon_2\Delta y $ where $\varepsilon_i$ are tending to zero as $(\Delta x,\Delta y)\to (0,0)$ ( and, in this case, $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$).

Answer (score 0):

In fact what you did is good. Your switch to polar coordinate is valid.

However you could have stayed in Cartesian coordinate. Taking the path $x=y$, you would have seen directly that $f_x$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ with  the same argument than the one you used in polar coordinate.